# How to auto authenticate my username and access token while using git push command?

Tags: git

I am tired of putting typing my **username and access token** every time I want to use the command `git push`
I have configured the global username and user email but then also it keep asking me the username, every time I want to push my local work to the remote origin.
And then comes the **access token**. I am tired of copy-pasting it again & again every time I want to push.
Please help me in resolving this. Feels like I am spending more time on the git command-line interface than on my project.

Comment: The `user.name` and `user.email` that you configure with `git config --global` *are not used* here. The `git push` command needs to *authenticate* and that authentication process uses *completely different data*. Git does not do authentication; Git shoves the job off on some other program. The program chosen depends on (a) your URL/protocol (https vs ssh, for instance) and then (b) your OS. Look up these two items and see how to configure whatever program Git is invoking.

Comment: Oh! That sounds good.

Comment: Note that Git has "credential helpers" that may assist here. There are different ones for different OSes, though: Windows has one or more Windows one, OSX has the osx-keychain credential helper. (They tend to come with the Git installation for your OS, but aren't exactly part of Git.)

Comment: Which OS are you using? Which way to connect to remote repo (HTTP or SSH)?

Comment: I am on Arch Linux. I prefer HTTP. If you know how to remember this, it will be really helpful. But I have also figured a way out, not in the way I would have liked to but yeah. As I am using VS code, it has a git authentication system, so I have authorized vs code to modify my repo, and now with a click vs code is doing it all. But anyway I would like to know if there's a way around in case I am in the terminal.

Comment: Your recent edit has removed info which is needed to clarify what you want, because the title alone is not clear enough. I will undo the removal of the long text. Feel free to fine tune your question without removing too much info.

Answer (score -1):

You don't, it has configured the email and others as a result root, it doesn't let you configure username and password, because of authentication, to avoid someone else pushing something....

Comment: So sad! But thank you for confirming. Now at least I won't feel like there's an option to make it simpler but I am not using it. 
Anyway, would you like to give any shortcuts to copy-pasting the authentication token again & again?

Comment: This is false. There are multiple ways to "remember" the authentication. As mentioned in another comment, it depends on your way to connect to the remote: HTTP or SSH.